# Sorting the results of a mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a search page on my site that lists a names of flowers

**PHP code :**

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM flowers
WHERE (`title` RLIKE '".$query."[.,?!]?[ ]') LIMIT 200") or die(mysql_error());
```

**Result :**

[image]

---

**I want to sort the results**

**Like this  :**

[image]

Full php code : search.php

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$min_length = 2;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){
$query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM flowers
WHERE (`title` RLIKE '".$query."[.,?!]?[ ]') LIMIT 200") or     die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

$str = $results['title'];
$keyword = $_GET['query'];
$str = preg_replace("/\w*?$keyword\w*/i", "<mark>$0</mark>", $str);
echo $str;

echo "<br>".$results['text']."<br>";
}
}

else { echo "No results"; }

}
else{ echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Comment: Your code is _**wide open** to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)_. Don't build queries by sticking strings together. Instead, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: I don't understand what your examples are trying to show. Please read [ask]. It is important that your question is as clear as possible. Consider showing us the query string you are trying to match against and a small dataset as a [mcve].

Comment: @Chris thank you for your explain Sir :) I will fix that ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I think something more like this:

```
order by ( concat(' ', title, ' ') like concat('% ', $title, ' %') ) desc,
         ( title like concat('%', $title, '%') ) desc,
         ( title rlike replace(title, ' ', '|') ) desc
         locate($title, title)
```

This does the following ordering:

- Exact matches (without punctuation) go first.
- Then exact matches with punctuation.
- Then partial matches.
- Within the first two groups, matches closer to the beginning of the text are preferred.